# retaining line breaks in email body

Tags: php, html

I have a feedback form where the user can enter his/her feedbacks in a textarea. When the form is submitted I am using the php mail function to get all the user details into my mail.

```
mail( "aaa@ddd.com", "Subject: Comments posted by $postedBy", $message, "From: $emailID" );
```

Here `$message` is the user comments. But I get something like this in the email body.

```
Hi.test line break\r\nnew line\r\nnewline 2\r\ntest again\r\nagain.
```

The line breaks in text area are showing up in the mail. How can I fix this?

Edit:

```
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
```

Comment: (Windows only) When PHP is talking to a SMTP server directly, if a full stop is found on the start of a line, it is removed. To counter-act this, replace these occurrences with a double dot.

<?php
$msg = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $msg);
?>

Comment: How do you set `$message`? Could you post the code for that line?

Comment: It's a pity to see another SPAM gateway...

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. I am new to web development. So I dint get what you meant by that.

Comment: However, if you still using mysql_real_escape_string on the other fields. it would be ridiculous, but it would protect this form from spam, lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the \r\n directly displayed or is all in one line without seeing \r\n?
For last I think you have to set the correct content-type.
In example 4 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php you can see how to set the content-type. But you have to use plain/text for that.

**EDIT:**
After your edit: mysql_real_escape maskes all linebreaks. use $_POST['comment'] on your mail()-call to have it working!

```
mail($to, $subject, $_POST['comment'], $from);
```

Comment: But what if the user enters some quotes ("" "" '') It will be show as \"\" in the mail

Comment: Maybe your server runs with magic_quotes, so you have to test for it and remove the slashes with stripslashes(). Have a look at example #1: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

Answer (score 2):

There is some function in your code that replaces newline characters with \r\n.
just trace your code and see, where this replacement takes place, and remove it.
Not a big deal

Comment: Yea. I was using mysql_real_escape. Thanx

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you've tried this but can you try replacing the "\r\n" with "<br>". 
Alternatively see if you can change the email mime type
Check this 
http://php.bigresource.com/Email-MIME-Types-KesYPexl.html

Comment: Given that there's no MIME header set in the `mail` call, it seems unlikely that this is HTML mail...

Comment: I am using simple mail. Not html mail